# Should I post an answer if I don't think it adds value to SO?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across a question with a relatively simple solution that I'm sure has been asked before, however my search technique wasn't finding a very good example on SO to point the OP towards. To help the OP, I answered in the comments and the OP advised that what I suggested worked for them.

OP now suggests that I post my comment as an answer so they can accept it and therefore give credit.

The thing is, I answered in the comments because I'm not interested in getting credit for this kind of question/answer, and more importantly I don't think either the question nor answer really needs to stay on SO. I can't see it ever ranking very high in search results because the question is not asked in general enough terms to apply to other people's experience of this problem (though it happens frequently enough). If it were modified to be more general then I'm sure it would just overlap existing questions/answers.

The OP of the question appears to be quite new though, and I feel like it would be rude to suggest back to them that they now delete their question. What is the correct etiquette in this situation?

Comment: Without seeing the question, my suggestions would be to see if you _can_ find a more general question for the problem. If you can, great! Close this as a dupe of that. (Flag it, in your case.) If you can't (and I advise checking again even if you already have, just in case you think of new search terms) then I suggest working with the OP to edit the question to be more general. Explain to them that we want questions and answers to help future users, and do so nicely, and you should be fine. If this can be done, then you should post your answer. (This is opinion hence my not posting an answer.)

Comment: @Kendra I see you found said question ;) I was avoiding posting a link to avoid the meta effect (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) Thanks for helping out though. I'm going to keep searching to see if I can find the "right" dupe question for it.

Comment: Avoiding the meta effect is admirable, though when you've participated on a post, it isn't 100% possible. ;) I just followed your profile to the comments you've left, simple enough. It doesn't look like a _terrible_ question, and it has argued that the subject is on-topic before, iirc. So a tip for the OP never hurts. But yeah, if you can find a good dupe for it (and I'll do a quick search if I can to help out) then it can be closed, if not it doesn't hurt to post an answer. I use the program often, and that's a trick I actually never knew so your "answer" is already helpful.

Comment: I did find one eventually, just posting another comment now...

Comment: I figured there would be one for that particular question. An easy answer, but not one a more casual user (such as myself) would find. Good find! :)

Comment: I think you add value by answering, even in this case. The value might not be very high. Of course you could also add your answer to some other question and refer to it in the comments.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you can't find a dupe target, you might as well answer it with an answer.

While it may not be adding value it certainly isn't removing or hiding potential value which is what would be happening if you left the answer within the comment. If someone did happen to come across the question it would be harder to find the comment answer.

Fortunately though in this case you were eventually able to find a dupe target.

If you feel bad about accepting rep for an answer to a question like this, you could always make the answer a community wiki.

Comment: I always forget about community wiki. Should use it one of these days.

Answer (score 16):

> I answered in the comments because I'm not interested in getting credit for this kind of question/answer

We already had similar discussions in the past. Related:

[Let's encourage the commenter with the correct answer to post it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242767/lets-encourage-the-commenter-with-the-correct-answer-to-post-it-as-an-answer)

[What should be done with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins)

You shouldn't post an answer as a comment. Answers should be posted as answers. As already said, if you are not concerned with the reputation for your answer, make it a community wiki.

Also, as @Shog9 [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242767/lets-encourage-the-commenter-with-the-correct-answer-to-post-it-as-an-answer#comment793485_242768), don't be surprised if someone else does the work for you and gets the credit.

> and more importantly I don't think either the question nor answer really needs to stay on SO

That's a completely different case. It is important to know the reason why you think the question needs to be removed. If you think the question doesn't have the merit to be on Stack Overflow, then downvote it and/or vote to close.

Comment: This brings up an interesting dilemma regarding timing. I understand that answering in comments is generally frowned upon, however it can buy the time needed to find the right dupe questions and possibly dissuade rep whores from snatching so called low hanging fruit. As it stands, my comment solved the OP's issue, but it offered no explanation as to *why* it worked. The linked dupe question however goes into more detail about why the OP's problem existed and why the solution works.

Comment: Also, I always feel bad downvoting new users when they've just reached 10-20 rep and unlocked some of the new user privileges. I know it's the "right" thing to do, but it just feels cruel. It's a lot easier once they've gotten past that point.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question would be incomplete without having among the answers at least one, which obviously adds no value to SO.

... or does it?

Comment: Is this an attempt to be meta on Meta?

Comment: If you are not meta while on Meta you are being off-topic, right?

Comment: I believe an incomplete question having, among the answers, none, may actually be better off than that which has one which adds no value to SO, as the attention might be directed to complete questions perhaps, which among them there is at least one answer which adds value to SO, or would it?

Comment: @Ike: valid point. Answering nothing is better than answering something irrelevant. However, the OP here describes a situation where he simply believes the answer is too trivial, even if though it is relevant and helpful.

Comment: @KT. Sorry, I was just trying to play back at you the playful wording. :-D But more seriously, I kind of think "too trivial" is kind of same as "irrelevant". An uber beginner question tends to manifest itself in the same basic issues duplicated again and again and again. Lately I've been also answering them in comments to avoid trying to allow them to be legitimized with an answer... only reason I'd want to provide an answer is if an accepted answer reduces views to that question... it's like I don't want to shine a spotlight on that Q or my basic, terse answer to it.

Comment: @KT. `"A: You forgot a semicolon."` (exaggerated example). I don't want to bump the question or even show people I give such answers in the form of a genuine answer. I'm hoping the comment can kind of satisfy the person who asked the Q and make the question disappear and get lost in the shuffle.

Comment: @Ike, well, all those "exaggerated examples" are typically obvious to close. The problem of the OP lies in the gray area inbetween, where one person may consider the answer useful while another not.

Comment: @KT. If in doubt then I'd suggest answering. I think there are plenty of cases where there is no doubt though.

Comment: @KT *Answering nothing is better...* Not sure what you mean by this. Are you saying to just leave without answering, or to provide answers where the question wasn't asked (canonicals), or something else?

Comment: @JoeMalpass, I mean that if you cannot answer something relevant, it is better not to answer at all and leave it to someone else. If you can provide relevant pointers, this is not the case. On the other hand, there may be cases where "irrelevant" answers might still be worth posting. Like this one here :)

Answer (score 1):

> If it were modified to be more general then I'm sure it would just
>   overlap existing questions/answers.

Is it one of those beginner troubleshooting MCVE type of questions?  For those I've adopted the habit lately of rigidly sticking only to comments for answers. It's my way of attempting to help this beginner out a bit but not pollute the site.

The main problem to me is that answers bump this uber basic question which doesn't benefit anyone but the author needlessly. When it's bumped, you might get FGITWs who end up bumping it even more.

These types of basic troubleshooters just don't help anybody else with their MCVEs and very narrowly-applicable questions. *"Q: What's wrong with my code? (well-stated question, clean MCVE, thus on-topic) A: You forgot a semicolon. A: You're accessing an array out of bounds."*

How does that help anyone, even a person at an equal beginner level? The question is too specific due to the MCVE, not broad and general enough. If it was like, `"What does a semicolon do in this language? How do arrays work?"`, maybe such a basic and general question would help some beginners out there.

But an MCVE question from a beginner is typically the same basic issues that beginners stumble over every time they approach programming for the first time, only duplicated tens of thousands of times, and just in tens of thousands of different variations of code which other beginners wouldn't understand let alone bother to digest anyway. Those questions are only useful for the immediate person who asks them, useless for anything else. And they waste the time of people who can provide an answer once answered (even in a comment) if they get bumped. These are disposable transient questions -- once answered, ideally tossed away, but at least not bumped up to keep receiving more attention.

So I think it's correct to refuse to provide an answer in these cases. We don't want to be bumping such questions up and drowning out much more interesting questions with genuine, unique issues behind them.

Comment: Maybe..? The question (which OP has since deleted) was basically asking "Why is this Excel formula not returning the expected result?", and the answer was "You omitted an optional argument/parameter". It's certainly a problem that many people encounter, since's Excel's built-in formula tips don't really emphasize the importance of said parameter when typing it in. I think it would have been a perfectly good question/answer pair for SO if it had not already been asked/answered before.

Comment: @JoeMalpass Ah I see, basic duplicate kind of troubleshooter. I think you made the right choice by not answering it.